# tex4ht doesn't render \not correctly

Tags: tex4ht

I tried to htlatex the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

Given two sets $A,B$ such that $A$ is not a subset of $B$, i.e., $A\not\subseteq B$.

\end{document}
```

It compiles `$\not\subseteq$` to something like `$/\subseteq$`. Is there a simple fix for that? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I refer to `\subseteq` just make things concrete (see an answer below for the usage of `\nsubseteq`. I wonder whether generally, `\not` could be modified to work for a general binary relation.

Comment: what is strange is that a correct symbol is rendered in the `html5` output, or with `epub3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the `uni-html4` option for tex4ht. It configures some characters to use the Unicode encoding:

```
tex4ebook filename.tex "uni-html4"
```

I've modified the tex4ebook sources to use this option by default, as it uses the Unicode output anyway.

The result:

[image]

```xml
<!--l. 7--><p class="noindent" >Given two sets <span 
class="cmmi-10">A,B </span>such that <span 
class="cmmi-10">A </span>is not a subset of <span 
class="cmmi-10">B</span>, i.e., <span 
class="cmmi-10">A</span>⊈<span 
class="cmmi-10">B</span>.
</p>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: can we pass "uni-html4" to htlatex and how?

Comment: @FrankScience sure, `htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,uni-html4"`. the `html5` option loads the Unicode declarations as well, which explain why `make4ht` produced a different output to `tex4ebook` - it uses the `html5` output by default.

Comment: I discovered that tex4ht with option uni-html4 will compile `\widehat` to `<span class='accentwidehat'>` which seems ignored by the browser.

Comment: @FrankScience you can try the `new-accents` option, it will convert hat to picture though. and it may have some side effects, I haven't explored this option fully yet.

Comment: @FrankScience ah, it needs to be `new-accents,accent-` option. and it needs LuaTeX or XeTeX to work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$\nsubseteq$` instead of `$\not\subseteq`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
Given two sets $A,B$ such that $A$ is not a subset of $B$, i.e., $A\nsubseteq B$.
\end{document}
```

### HTML Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html > 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)"> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)"> 
<!-- html --> 
<meta name="src" content="temp245.tex"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="temp245.css"> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 6--><p class="noindent" >Given two sets <span 
class="cmmi-10">A,B </span>such that <span 
class="cmmi-10">A </span>is not a subset of <span 
class="cmmi-10">B</span>, i.e., <span 
class="cmmi-10">A </span><span 
class="msbm-10">&#x2288; </span><span 
class="cmmi-10">B</span>.  
</body></html>
```

### Rendered HTML:

Given two sets *A*,*B* such that *A* is not a subset of *B*, i.e., *A* ⊈ *B*.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I knew `\nsubseteq`. I am, however, trying to understand whether we can make `\not` generally working.

Comment: @FrankScience, oh! Sorry, misunderstood. I don't know, but interesting question.

Comment: Well, that's due to the fact that I did not succeed to properly phrase the question, not a mistake from your part. And this answer should be useful for others (for example, it will be shown in the result of googling `tex4ebook not subseteq`).